# How can i customize edges in cytoscape.js so that lines are dashed and animated/flashing?

Tags: javascript, customization, cytoscape.js, edges

I have  graph in cytoscape.js and i want some of the edges to be dashed (or something similar) and a specific edge to have an effect animation like (blinking, animated, having something moving over it ..something like that). Are there any examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can find these things at the official documentation:

In order to make edges dotted or dashed, do as said [here](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/edge-line)

```
cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    elements: {
        nodes: [
            ...
        ],
        edges: [
            ...
        ]
    },

    layout: {
        ...
    },    
    style: [{
        selector: 'edge',
        style: {
            'line-style': 'data(style)' //e.g dotted
        }
    }]
});
```

Animations are also explained in the docs [here](http://js.cytoscape.org/#animations). If you need help with the animations, you will have to be more specific and provide the code (what you have tried already).

Comment: The style works fine. About the animation i want to make the edges dashed and moving like marching ants, so i tried something like :var jAni = cy.$('edge').animation({
  
style: {
       'curve-style': 'bezier',
                            'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
                            'width': 2,
       'line-style': 'dashed',
       'line-dash-pattern': [6, 3], 
       'line-dash-offset': 24,
                            'line-color': '#ddd',
                            'target-arrow-color': '#ddd'
      },
  duration: 5000
});

jAni.play();  but is not working